# Can I set the height of a progressBar to half the height of it's parent in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

Not Just the height of the progressBar but the actual progress track too, they seem to have different properties. I'm already using the layout weight of for it's horizontal length, but it has no effect on its height.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ProgressBar` has a proportionate height and width attributes, meaning you can't have a bigger height value than an width otherwise it'll look skewed.  (I could be wrong, but from playing around with the `View` that's what it seems like.)

If you're using a `layout_weight` value for the width, then it will have no effect on the height, you can set your height to be `match_parent` and the size you get will be the maximum size based on the width.

To set your `ProgressBar` at 50% use `progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getMax()/2)` or if you know the max value ahead of time, you can hard-code the 50%.

Comment: I don't think it is proportional, The progress track seems to have a fix dp value. However, you can: setScaleY(int). Which changes the progress track only. However, What value should I put inside? The parent is a LinearLayout, what value can I get from it that can allow make the track progress a proportion height.

Comment: Can you clarify your questions? `setScale` is inherited from the `View` class so yes you can do that, but you might have unwanted results as `ProgressBar` has it's own logic. I'm not sure what you mean by progress track. Scaling shouldn't have anything to do with your progress.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to set the scale of the progress track to exactly half of the parent:

```
LinearLayout progView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progView);
ProgressBar xpBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.xpBar);

xpBar.setScaleY(progView.getScrollBarSize()/2);
```